# Draw a red circle around the max value of calcium attribute (ind=19,value=290) or in general any outlier in df fastfood of library(openintro) using R

Tags: r, outliers

I have recently started my journey in R and Data Science in generakl

I have written this code so far

```
`install.packages("openintro")
library(openintro)
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

#load data 
data(fastfood)
#Find calcium's max value and indice
max.calcium <- max(na.omit(fastfood$calcium))
max.calcium
indices <- which(fastfood$calcium== max.calcium, arr.ind = TRUE)
indices

ggplot(fastfood, aes(x=seq_along(fastfood$calcium),y =calcium)) +
  geom_point() +
 xlab("Index")+  ylab("Calcium") +
  ggtitle("Scatterplot of X vs Y with Outliers Highlighted") +
    theme_bw()``
```

How can I use ggplot() to mark for this attribute"calcium" the max value point with a red circle around it?

I have already written this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a single point at `x = ind, y = max.calcium`. This can be added via another `geom_point` layer. Use a large sized point (say, `size = 5`), make it red, and make it a hollow circle shape (`shape = 21, fill = NA`):

```r
ggplot(fastfood, aes(x = seq_along(calcium), y = calcium)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(aes(x = indices, y = max.calcium),
             color = 'red', size = 5, shape = 21, fill = NA) +
  xlab("Index") +  
  ylab("Calcium") +
  ggtitle("Scatterplot of X vs Y with Outliers Highlighted") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Allan!Before my post here,I searched quite a lot on the internet on how to do that without having found clear guidance